# Why 'error:' callback is being invoked

Tags: jquery

This is how I am invoking the click :

```
$("#myDivId").click(function(e) {
callAjax();
window.location = 'localhost://myhomepage'
});
```

Within error the error callback I have this :

```
function callAjax(){
$.ajax({
            url: "myurl",       
            type: 'POST',
            dataType : "text",
            data : ({
                json : myjson
            }),
            success : function(data) {

            },
   error : function() {
        console.log("readyState: "+xhr.readyState);
        console.log("status: "+xhr.status);
        console.log("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    } 

        }); 
}
```

The console output is :

```
readyState : 0
status : 0
responseText :
```

Since the console output is not useful, if success is being called why is the error callback being invoked?

If I remove the window.location call after the call to callAjax the error callback is not invoked.

Comment: This should not happen (the `success` and `error` handlers are mutually exclusive). Can you post your complete call to `$.ajax()`?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi thats a mistake, success is not being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your code.

`ReadyState 0` means: The object has been created, but not initialized (the open method has not been called). [☛source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So the Ajax call is not sent at all. Please post more details from your code. What is the network-console saying?

Comment: ive updated my question to include more detail that I have just discovered

Comment: @user470184 you are not allowed to call `www.google.com` - this is a cross-domain call and for security reasons forbidden. It's called Same Origin Policy (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy)

Comment: I've updated to redirect to same domain but same issue (question updated)

Comment: why are you changing the location? the ajax call is asynchronous, this means, it is not done at the moment you are changing window.location - thus possibly interrupting the call. Move the `window.location` into your success-function.

Comment: ok, but changing the order of the calls so the redirect occurs before the callAjax function is called should also fix this ?

Comment: @user470184 You can't redirect to another page and do the ajax call afterwards.